# R DT::datatable converted to png when knitting to wordpress with knit2wp()

Tags: r, wordpress, r-markdown, knitr, dt

As title says, I can render a datatable to html, but when calling knit2wp() sending to my self-hosted install I get a png image of my datatable in the post. How do I fix this to get interactive datatable in my wordpress post?

The relevant lines are:

```
des <- generateDesign(n=15,
                      par.set = getParamSet(obj.fun),
                      fun = lhs::randomLHS)
DT::datatable(des, options = list(scrollX = TRUE,
                                  pageLength = 15,
                                  dom = 'tir')) %>%
  DT::formatRound(c(1:2, 5:8))
```

And if you want to see the html, you can see it [here](https://michael-barr.com/datasci/bayesian-mbo) (find 'datatable' on the page and see image below). Could this be due to this line of the knit2wp() function?: `content = enc2utf8(content)`